# AngularJS "10 $digest() iterations reached" in Internet Explorer dealing with a custom filter

Tags: arrays, angularjs, internet-explorer, filter, infinite-loop

Our project is using a custom filter to provide sorting and filtering of items in a list.  It takes two arguments, the list, and a filter type parameter that determines the sort/filter scheme to apply.  The filter appears to be responsible for a "10 $digest() iterations reached" error in Internet Explorer (only).  The business end of the filter is below:

```
return function(players, filterType) {
    switch (filterType) {
        case 'Money':
            return players.sort(function (a, b) {
                if (a.IsSelf) return -1;
                if (a.WinnerPrizeMoney == b.WinnerPrizeMoney) return 0;
            if (b.IsSelf || a.WinnerPrizeMoney < b.WinnerPrizeMoney) return -1;
            if (a.IsSelf || a.WinnerPrizeMoney > b.WinnerPrizeMoney) return 1;
            return 0;
        });
        case 'Tracked Players':
        var trackedPlayers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
            if (players[i].IsTracked || players[i].IsSelf) {
                trackedPlayers.push(players[i]);
            }
        }
        return trackedPlayers;
        case 'Connections':
        var connectedPlayers = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < players.length; j++) {
            if (players[j].IsConnected || players[j].IsSelf) {
                connectedPlayers.push(players[j]);
            }
        }
        return connectedPlayers;
        case 'Rank':
            return players.sort(function (a, b) {
                if (a.IsSelf) return -1;
                if (a.WinnerPosition == b.WinnerPosition) return 0;
            if (b.IsSelf || a.WinnerPosition < b.WinnerPosition) return -1;
            if (a.IsSelf || a.WinnerPosition > b.WinnerPosition) return 1;
            return 0;
        });
    default:
    }
};
```

Two of the filter types sort the items, the other two filter the items.  The problem presents almost as soon as the page loads and gets items to filter, and initially the filterType is set to 'Rank'.

I have read that array.sort modifies the array in place, (i.e. it does not return a new array).  Is my understanding on that count correct?  .sort would not cause this problem as it is returning the same array it came in with, the items are just changed in position.  That applies to filterTypes of 'Money' and 'Rank'.

For 'Tracked Players' and 'Connections' is there a better way to handle those than by creating a new array and pushing specific items into it according to the filter?  While this does not appear to be the culprit in this instance, it seems to fit the mold that others have suggested as possible causes in other SO articles regarding this error.

I feel like I am spinning my wheels on this, I spent about 6 hours yesterday ("after work") fiddling with this trying to diagnose and fix it.  I have narrowed it down to the filtering mechanism above, but other than that, I am having no luck.

## Update

This seems to have specifically to do with Internet Explorer.  I tested the filter in Chrome and Firefox and it was only hit once per filterType change (e.g. user changes the value of the Filter dropdown which in turn changes the filterType and fires off the filter.

Internet Explorer however repeatedly hits the filter.  And only when filterType = 'Rank'.  I don't get that though.  Rank and Money have almost the exact same sorting scheme, just on different properties.

Just to be sure that this did not have something to do with the fact that I set filterType = 'Rank' in the initialization of the controller, I changed it to all three of the other values in turn.  No problems.  This now seems specifically to do with possibly the comparison of the values WinnerPosition (numeric) or with some value somehow changing on the item being sorted.

## Stepping Through Execution Update

OK, so I may need someone to enlighten me.  The $watchCollectionWatch function (angular.js:12307 in my case) iterates through the items in each collection on the scope and checks the oldValue (i.e. what was passed into the filter in this case) with the newValue (what came back)  if the two are different it increments changeDetected signaling that a collection has changed.  When a collection changes that has a filter on it, it re-runs the filter.  In my case I am changing the ordering of the collection and thus every time the filter gets run, it reads it as having changed.  How to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing this around so that instead of having the filter above registered as such with the app, I put it on the controller called by ng-change on the drop down that the user specifies the filter with.

I changed the code a little.  I store Players in both $scope.Players and $scope.StoragePlayers.  StoragePlayers holds the empirical set of Players.  $scope.Players is what the list of players on the page is bound to.  I modify $scope.Players and only read from $scope.StoragePlayers.

## New Version

```
    $scope.NewFilter = function () {
        switch ($scope.SelectedFilter) {
            case 'Money':
                $scope.Players = $scope.StoragePlayers.sort(function (a, b) {
                    if (a.IsSelf) return -1;
                    if (a.WinnerPrizeMoney == b.WinnerPrizeMoney) return 0;
                    if (b.IsSelf || a.WinnerPrizeMoney < b.WinnerPrizeMoney) return -1;
                    if (a.IsSelf || a.WinnerPrizeMoney > b.WinnerPrizeMoney) return 1;
                    return 0;
                });
                break;
            case 'Tracked Players':
                var trackedPlayers = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.StoragePlayers.length; i++) {
                    if ($scope.StoragePlayers[i].IsTracked || $scope.StoragePlayers[i].IsSelf) {
                        trackedPlayers.push($scope.StoragePlayers[i]);
                    }
                }
                $scope.Players = trackedPlayers;
                break;
            case 'Connections':
                var connectedPlayers = [];
                for (var j = 0; j < $scope.StoragePlayers.length; j++) {
                    if ($scope.StoragePlayers[j].IsConnected || $scope.StoragePlayers[j].IsSelf) {
                        connectedPlayers.push($scope.StoragePlayers[j]);
                    }
                }
                $scope.Players = connectedPlayers;
                break;
            case 'Rank':
                $scope.Players = $scope.StoragePlayers.sort(function (a, b) {
                    if (a.IsSelf) return -1;
                    if (a.WinnerPosition == b.WinnerPosition) return 0;
                    if (b.IsSelf || a.WinnerPosition < b.WinnerPosition) return -1;
                    if (a.IsSelf || a.WinnerPosition > b.WinnerPosition) return 1;
                    return 0;
                });
                break;
            default:
        }
```